# Elasticsearch single request to do Union query Top N

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Not sure how to do SQL like **union** in Elasticsearch. I tried **bool** query but it doesn't meet my requirement yet. For example, the document structure is

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "authorId": 28,
  "title": "Five Ways to Tap into...",
  "byLine": "ashd jsabbdjs international",
  "category": "Cat1"
}
```

I need to find top 5 matched **"title"** in each **"category"** when user types something. This can be done using multiple queries to Elasticsearch, but I was wondering if there are other ways to do it in one request.

Answer (score 1):

Use an aggregation with `top_hits` sub-aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_5": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is query which returns multi buckets based on **"category"**

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "authorId": [
                     1,
                     28
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "query_string": {
                  "query": "*int*",
                  "fields": [
                     "title^2",
                     "byLine^1"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "categories": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "category",
            "size": 10
         },
         "aggs": {
            "top_5": {
               "top_hits": {
                  "size": 5
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```